# "An install, uninstall, or conversion is in progress for this distribution"

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

In an attempt to install WSL and Ubuntu, when I enter the  install command, "wsl --install", instead of asking me to create a username and password, it shows: "An install, uninstall, or conversion is in progress for this distribution." How do I complete the installation process from there?

Answer (score 1):

This can be a tough one to resolve, as (according to the lead WSL developer [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7817#issuecomment-992694483)) it indicates that the WSL service likely crashed while the Ubuntu distribution was being installed, leaving it in a bad state.

*Hopefully*, just unregistering Ubuntu and trying again will work, but if WSL is crashing due to some system issue, then it may happen again.

Let's start with, from PowerShell (regular user, not admin):

```
wsl --shutdown
wsl -l -v
```

- Confirm the name of the distribution, likely "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu-22.04"
- Note: the following will destroy all data in the existing distribution, which shouldn't be a problem since it never completed in the first place.  However, just make sure that you are unregistering the proper distribution if you have more than one.

```
wsl --unregister <distribution_name>
```

- Go to the Microsoft Store, find [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage) there.  If not installed, install it -- It's the latest release.
- Go to the Microsoft Store, find "Ubuntu" (no version) or "Ubuntu 22.04" and trying installing from there.

If the problem reoccurs, see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7817#issuecomment-993238757) and check the group policy settings.